# jq exclude key for output

Tags: bash, shell, filter, jq

I need to exclude field `_class` from this output:

```json
{
  "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
  "displayName": "NAME-(#1498)",
  "number": 1498
}
```

What I use for get this json

```bash
curl -gn http://<jenkins-site>/job/<build-name>/api/json?tree=builds[displayName,number]&pretty=true | jq -r '.builds[] | select(.displayName | contains("NAME"))'
```

Result must be just:

```json
{
  "displayName": "NAME-(#1498)",
  "number": 1498
}
```

I tried using `|not` and `del`, but that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply delete that field using `del`:

```bash
… | jq '.builds[] | select(.displayName | contains("NAME")) | del(._class)'
```

```json
{
  "displayName": "NAME-(#1498)",
  "number": 1498
}
```

Note: If you output JSON, the `-r` flag isn't doing anything.